# Launch a file created in RAM memory

Tags: java, file-io, ram, fileinputstream

I've been asked to launch an Excel file, created at RunTime inside the **RAM memory**.

For example, with:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\....\fileName.xlsx"));
```

I can "launch" Excel program that open the file "c:....\fileName.xlsx".

Since my file is created inside the **RAM memory** this way:

```
 ...

     FileSystemManager fsm = VFS.getManager();
     FileObject RAM = fsm.resolveFile("ram://ramFileName.xlsx");
     OutputStream os = RAM.getContent().getOutputStream();
     FileInputStream sorgente = new FileInputStream("C:\\originalFile.xlsx");   
     int singloByte;

     while ((singloByte = sorgente.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(singloByte);
     }
     sorgente.close();
     os.close();
     ...
```

is there a way to open a file created only in **RAM memory** and **not in file system**?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel files can't be "launched". What `Desktop.open()` does is finds the default handler for the file (presumably Excel in this case), and launches the handler with the given file as a parameter.

Since Excel can't open "in-memory files" (AFAIK), you have no choice but to write it to a temporary file to open it.

Answer (score 2):

@Kayaman's answer is correct (nearly).

> Since Excel can't open "in-memory files" (AFAIK) ...

is absolutely correct, if we are talking about a Java VFS "ram:" file system.

Firstly we need to understand the difference between a normal file system and a Java VFS.

A normal file system is one that the operating system supports.  An application accesses a normal file system by making system calls (`open`, `read`, `write`, `seek`, `opendir`, etcetera) that cross the user-space to kernel-space boundary.  The kernel may deal with the request in different ways depending on the file system type; e.g. NFTS, FAT, a mounted SMB share, etcetera.  Or in some operating systems, the requests may be passed to a user-space file system; e.g. a loop-back file system where a ISO image or a ZIP file is mounted as a file system.

The key thing about a normal file systems is that the application sees them all (pretty much) the same, and accesses them using standard syscalls.

By contrast, a Java VFS is an abstraction where the common API is implemented by the Java library rather than by the operating system.  For example, a Java `read(...)` method call for a stream will be mapped to a call on the VFS object.  This may be dispatched to a real file system (via a syscall), or to a virtual file system implemented within the JVM.  A "ram:" VFS could be represented using memory allocated from the Java heap or the native heap.

The Excel application is a native application.  Native applications can talk to normal file systems, in the same way that a Java application would; via the syscalls.  But since it the Excel application is not running within the address space of the JVM that holds your "ram:" VFS, there is no way that it can access it.

---

But that's not the end of the story.  There are a couple of ways that you *could* get Excel to read from an in-memory file.

Some operating systems support a "normal" file system that lives in RAM ... or virtual memory.   For example, a typical Linux system will use a "tmpfs" file system to hold the "/tmp" directory.  So, on Linux you could arrange for your Java application to write files into a "tmpfs" file system, and then pass the pathname to an application like Excel.  On Windows, I think you need to use 3rd-party RAM disk software; see the following page:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software

The second approach is more complicated.  I mentioned above that SMB network shares are accessed as "normal" file systems.  SMB is actually a network protocol that allows a client (your local operating system) to access files on the SMB file server.  Now it is at least theoretically possible for a Java application to implement the server-side of the SMB protocol, and use its heap to store the "files" that it serves up to a client.  So ... hypothetically ... you could start your SMB-server-in-a-Java-application, and then get the operating system to mount it as a network share.  Then your Excel application could read and write files from the Java application's memory via the share.

I wouldn't call that a practical approach (unless you have deep pockets!), but I know of a Java-based platform that *does* do this kind of thing; exposing its "repository" to clients via its own Java implementations of the NFS, S3 and other protocols.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting lesson :)

Comment: I thought of ram drive, but I didn't think it's a very valid mechanism anymore :)

Comment: No comment about Windows :-).  It is a valid solution on Linux, etc where tmpfs is integrated with the OS.